# Unwind from a button in a table view controller inside a nav controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following controllers in a storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

The navigation controller is segued to by a button in the main view controller on the left. It appears in a popover. When the user clicks the "Sign Out" button at the top of the table view controller on the right, I need to segue back to the main view controller, call a method that performs the signing out, and then display an authentication view controller (the app cannot be used if the user isn't signed in). Every way I've tried to do this has failed.

1. I can almost do it with an unwind segue, but if in my unwind method in the main view I launch the authentication view controller I get an "Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress" warning. Setting a timer to wait some arbitrary time for the dismissal to complete seems like a hack. (I wish there was a "your segue has just completed" callback.)
2. I can't do it by setting the main view controller as the delegate of the settings controller in the prepareForSegue method and calling a delegate method on it when the button is clicked, which would be the norm, because the destinationViewController in the segue isn't my settings controller, it's the navigation controller that houses it.

There's some obvious way to do this, right? Maybe by attaching the button to a method in the settings view controller that dismisses itself and then fires off an NSNotification in the completion block? That still seems hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the main view controller the delegate of the settings controller in the prepareForSegue method, by using:

```
 SettingsViewcontroller *settings =  [(UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
settings.delegate = self;
```

I think you could then call the delegate method in the settings controller's viewDidDisappear method.

Comment: For whatever reason I can't seem to get the popover to dismiss, but your solution seems to clearly be the right one so I'm accepting it. Thank you.